# how to hide status bar in flutter with video player and chewie

Tags: flutter, dart, video, statusbar, video-player

**this SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays didnt work with me in the initState the problem in the fullscreen
this is my initState**

```
void initState() {
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
        super.initState();
        _chewieController = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
          looping: widget.loop,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          autoInitialize: true,
          autoPlay: false,
          showControls: true,
          showControlsOnInitialize: true,
          fullScreenByDefault: true,
          allowFullScreen: true,
          deviceOrientationsOnEnterFullScreen: [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft],
          deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
        );
      }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?